# How do I use COUNT() on a couple of columns?

Tags: mysql, count

I have a MySQL server with a table (watchlist) that has two columns, "name" and "account", which together are primary key, and I have a second table (watchlistelement) that has also "watchlist" and "account", that reference the first table, and then a third column "element", which has the ID of the element.

I want to write a query that gives me the name and account of all watchlists (so empty ones too) and counts how many elements each watchlist has. I can't figure out how to use COUNT and GROUP BY to achieve this. My current query is this:

```
SELECT watchlist.name, watchlist.account, COUNT(watchlistelement.elementID) as 'elements#'
FROM watchlist
LEFT JOIN watchlistelement on watchlist.account = watchlistelement.account 
GROUP BY watchlistelement.watchlist, watchlistelement.account
```

The counts comes off too high for some lists, because it counts from all the lists of the account.

What am I doing wrong? How could I solve this?

UPDATE: I have realized that I made a mistake by not using both parts of the composite key in the JOIN. I have changed my query now and it seems to work:

```
SELECT watchlist.name, watchlist.account,COUNT(watchlistelement.content) as 'element#'
FROM watchlist 
LEFT JOIN watchlistelement on watchlist.account = watchlistelement.account AND watchlist.name = watchlistelement.watchlist 
GROUP BY watchlistelement.watchlist, watchlistelement.account;
```

watchlistelement.watchlist refers to watchlist.name, and both contain the name of the watchlist created by the user.

Comment: What does "watchlist" field in "watchlistelement" table reference to?

Comment: You might want to show some sample data to make it clear, as to what you want.

Comment: @PhúcĐỗVương "watchlist" in watchlistelement contains the name of the watchlist, so it refers to watchlist.name. I apologize for not making this clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I am not how this query is working because you need to give all the fields in the GROUP BY clause which you have mentioned in the SELECT other than cumulative function COUNT.

Second thing, you said "account" and "name" are
Composite key. So if you are not using both of them to join it might produce different results.
But if there is no similar column to name in watchlistement then account is the only option.

BUT YOU SHOULD USE BOTH THESE COLUMNS WHILE GROUPING. ACCOUNT AND NAME.

SELECT watchlist.name, watchlist.account, COUNT(watchlistelement.elementID) as 'elements#'
FROM watchlist
LEFT JOIN watchlistelement on watchlist.account = watchlistelement.account
GROUP BY watchlistelement.name, watchlistelement.account

Please tell what is watchlist in watchlistement to help me understand it more.

Comment: "watchlist" in watchlistelement contains the name of the watchlist, so it refers to watchlist.name. I apologize for not making this clear earlier.

Comment: I have actually figured out my mistake with the join, and I have changed my query. I will update the question with the new query. Please tell me if there is something wrong with the new query.